# Jquery selector not working after knockout.js applyBindings()

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have several inputs of the form:

```
<input data-bind="value:someKOObservable" />
```

And I want to access these with a Jquery selector after the data-bind event.  I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
    console.log("Found " + $("input").length + "  inputs.");

});
```

For some reason this does not find any input fields, but if I remove the applyBindings, then it finds all of them.

How do I use Jquery to select these inputs after the ko.applyBindings()?

Comment: No problem running this in FF17 or IE8: http://jsfiddle.net/8gBNF/1/

Comment: You're right it works fine.  My problem was that the inputs are being loaded with AJAX so I just need to bind to the $(document).ajaxComplete event instead of the $(document).ready event.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this happen also when using the 'with' binding. Removing the with binding should fix it.

Another way of dealing with this is to create a custom binding. It will receive an update call once it's ready for DOM processing.

```
   ko.bindingHandlers.myCustomBinding = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
   //I'm ready to update DOM
    } };
```

Answer (score -1):

use jquery delegate. you can find more info [here](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)